# What is the approximate horsepower/kW output of a cyclist riding a bike at near ~300km/h?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, aerospace-engineering, aerodynamics, electric-vehicles

In 2018, a female cyclist set the outdoors record for fastest cycling clocking in at almost 300km/h. (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denise_Mueller-Korenek), and I am curious to know the approximate output power necessary to achieve this.

**Why**

The angle of the question is to figure out whether there is a reasonable possibility that a Jetson ONE — which has a continuous max. output of 118 kW (88 hp) while flying — through some serious gear work and probably minute-range pre-acceleration, could be lifted off merely by human power, say, pedaling inside its small cabin — and/or alternatively, to figure out how much one could extend the range of one if pedaling throughout the flight?

Comment: What was the power of the car she was drafting behind?

Comment: There was a 62:12 gear ratio and had to be pulled to 100mph to turn over that gear ratio.  Combine that with shield blocking wind and a dragster pulling shield.  So the question is a tad unrealistic.

Comment: There are literally thousands of reports on elite cyclists' power/endurance curves, and the training and drug regime used to achieve that performance. For other pedal-powered endeavors, you need to be a little careful. The bicycling curves don't necessarily transfer blindly to other machines. Pedal powered boats and pedal powered planes were both researched by Drela at MIT, and he set records in both.  See *Project Icarus* and Decavitator.  2400 - 2500 W has been recorded in Olympic Pursuit cyclists and in world-class BMX. They are making more torque than a school bus diesel.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to realize here that the speed achieved by Denise Meuller would never be possible without the vehicle traveling in front of her. This vehicle created a low-pressure area right behind it. This low-pressure area effectively sucks a rider forward. From what I understand, the rider is mainly pedaling to control their distance from the vehicle: you cannot be too far or too close to the vehicle. Controlling this distance and controlling the bike in general at such speeds is where the main challenge lies in such a record.

As an estimate to how much power one would have to output to cycle at 300 km/h without a pace car, we can extrapolate [data of speed/power at lower speeds](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiNu8fk0fv7AhUAiP0HHdL_CcAQFnoECBIQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.road-bike.co.uk%2Farticles%2Fcycling-power.php&usg=AOvVaw374Tor8UCB3VRwrvrQz4jU). Extrapolating according to a second order polynomial (This is often done for drag + air resistance), we obtain the following using Excel, with y in Watts, and x in km/h:

> y = 0.2817x<sup>2</sup> - 2.3306x + 1.6627

Now filling in x = 300 (km/h), we get y = 24655 Watt, or 25 kW. This is completely unfeasible for a human. It's difficult to state exactly how much power she had to generate in order to stay with the vehicle. Much more information about the vehicle and bike is needed for such a figure. But I don't think it's relevant for your question.

I guess what you really want to know is 'How much power can a human maximally generate on a bike?'. According to a quick google search, an average human can generate about [300-400 Watt](http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2014/ph240/labonta1/#:%7E:text=The%20average%20human%2C%20at%20rest,can%20output%20over%202%2C000%20watts.) for a couple of minutes. A professional track cyclist can output about [2500 Watts](https://sportsmedicine-open.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s40798-021-00341-7#:%7E:text=Maximum%20power%20values%20as%20high,track%20sprint%20cyclists%20%5B39%5D.), nowhere near the 25kW we needed for 300km/h.

Some attempts have been made in building a pedal-powered drone like vehicles. [Take off has been achieved,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=emK-qIbuJ-k) but longer flights have not yet been achieved.

Comment: There is a sweet spot. I used to slipstream double-decker buses on my bike in my schooldays. There was a point about 60 cm from the back of the bus where there seemed to be no wind resistance. With the rear engine it was also warm in winter and reasonably dry. I always checked that the brake lights were working when I pulled in behind them to start the chase. There were no cheap digital speedometers in my youth so I can't say what speed I achieved but probably about 30 mph / 50 kph.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat the found parameters will depend on the cost function used for fitting the data. I'm not sure what Excel uses, but it's just a ballpark figure anyway.